# Does CBT indirectly resolve core issues?

Tags: therapy, cbt

(I don't expect that it would do so as successfully as interventions that aim to do so directly, but:)

From the outside, it seems CBT ignores the root causes of the issue, some may say building on sand (I'm pretty sure there's some such expression but I can't recall it)

My question is, does CBT actually help resolve core issues (any belief/emotional response a clinical psychologist might see as detrimental to the psychological and/or physical health of his patient and from which the problems the therapist wishes to resolve likely stem) indirectly? Do we affect our core issues in order to resolve the conflict one might cause by creating a new behavior that is incompatible with said issues?

Comment: As your definition of "core issues" is **detrimental beliefs and emotional responses**, I would say that my answer in https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1977 will answer this.

Comment: @ChrisRogers could you be more specific? the only thing I find relevant to my question is "CBT cannot and does not incorporate any psychodynamic theories", and "The psychodynamic approach suggests that our early experiences... lead to our psychological problems, where behavior theory sees problems as much more agreeable to change". So the approaches are incompatible, but my question has to do with the effects of the methods used in CBT *beyond* the ones directly intended, unless you're arguing that the theory behind CBT can account for every single change it brings, which I don't think you are

Comment: @user1999728 - A particularly key point in the answer is that it states *"CBT works by trying to get the client to think about a situation in a more helpful way in order to move forward using more helpful behaviours."* so it directly works on detrimental beliefs and emotional responses.